# Winforms toolstrip has weird thing

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I've been making a program using Winforms in C#. I was using Toolstrips when I noticed there's a weird black thing on the right side of the toolstrip.
 [image: this is image yes]
As you can see, there's a black line on the right side of the toolstrip. Any ideas what that is and how to fix it? It's really disturbing.

Comment: I'd suggest inspecting it with a tool like HawkEye http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/ and see if it belongs to the Toolstip or not

Comment: @Ian, it is actually part of the toolstrip! It even moves with it when I resize the window :/

Comment: It looks like a border or something has been drawn incorrectly. Have you tested on a different version of Windows? Have you got any custom GDI painting code?

Comment: @Ian Nothing custom, just plain ol' toolstrips I added. I have tested with another PC I have (also Win8.1) and it also draws the weird black line.